# Is there a universal way of iterating over a set or values of a dict in Python 2.7?

Tags: python

I expect the collection to be either a set or a dict. Problem is that:

```
for element in collection:
    print element
```

will give me the elements if collection is a set, but indexes if collection is a dict. What I want is a one-liner that will iterate over dict values.

Is that possible?

Comment: There are probably clever tricks to do this (`getattr(type(collection), 'values', iter)(collection)` comes to mind, but I'd never recommend to do that), but any such oneliner would be an overly clever hack. Is there a way to avoid this? And what's wrong with a more explicit check (which would have to span multiple lines)?

Comment: @delnan That's definitely the wrong way, but also quite clever. Now I have to think of some horrible ways to use default values like that...

Comment: Why don't you know what type you're getting in?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most foolproof way to test for a mapping is to use `isinstance` on [`collections.Mapping`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Mapping):

```
import collections

for element in (collection.values() 
                if isinstance(collection, collections.Mapping) else collection):
```

If you need to do that frequently (you shouldn't, or you probably have a design issue), you could move it into a function:

```
def values(collection):
    return (collection.values() 
                  if isinstance(collection, collections.Mapping) else collection)

for element in values(collection):
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import collections

def values(collection):
    for v in collection.values() if isinstance(collection, collections.Mapping) else collection:
        yield v

for element in values(collection):
    print element
```

Edit: I've copied the [`collections.Mapping` suggestion from agf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10319923/5987). My answer differs by implementing the solution as a function. I find Python to be incredibly useful for breaking a problem down into reusable pieces.

Comment: There is no need to make it a generator. You can just move the conditional expression I use in my answer into a function (I've edited that in to my answer), and you avoid a level of indirection.

Comment: @agf, your function uses a generator expression which is much the same as a `yield`, correct? Anyway +1 from me.

Comment: @MarkRansom There's no generator expression in his answer - it would indeed be the same thing, but there's only a conditional expression.

Comment: @delnan, you're right. A generator expression would have a `for` somewhere in it. Not my best day so far.

Answer (score -4):

How about:

```
def vals(c):
    try: return c.values()
    except: return c

for a in vals(whatever):
    ...
```

Especially for those brainwashed about bare except being "bad practice":

```
find "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework" -name "*.py" | xargs grep "except:" | wc -l
2901
```

go tell them.

Comment: If you were more explicit in the `except`, this would be a Pythonic answer. It's the exception version of `x.values() if hasattr(x, 'values') else x` which isn't very different from my answer; using duck typing is perfectly appropriate here.

Comment: @agf: the point was to show OP that their problem can (and should) be solved without explicit type checking (which smells like hell).